# How to prove that $\left(\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}\right)_{n\geq 0}$ is a null sequence. (a sequence tending to 0)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How to prove that $\left(\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}\right)_{n\geq 0}$. First of all, I realised that for $n=0$, we have an undetermined expression... Is that a possible mistake in the task?

**Nevermind, my attempt:**

$$\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}=\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{n}}{\prod_{k=1}^{2n}{k}}$$
Is there any rule to rewrite $\prod_{k=1}^{2n}{k}$ such that I can cancel the expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\prod \limits_{k=1}^{2n} k = n! \prod \limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} k > n! \prod \limits_{k=n+1}^{2n} n = n! n^n$. So the sequence is less than $\frac{1}{n!}$ which clearly tends to $0$.

Comment: Is $\left(\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}\right)_{n\geq 0}$ even right in the first place? Shouldn't it be $n\geq 1$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic $0!$ and $0^0$ are both actually defined as $1$. Regardless, it doesn’t affect the question too much.

Comment: $0^0$ is undefined... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero

Comment: Google 0^0. It should come up.

Comment: That underpins my statement. "[...] the generally agreed upon value is 0^0=1, wheras in mathematical analysis, the expression is generally left undefined."

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic Ah, I wasn’t aware of that subtlety. In that case, $n \geq 1$ is probably more correct.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your answer. How do you get $\frac 1{n!}$?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic We have $\frac{n^n}{(2n)!} < \frac{n^n}{n! n^n} = \frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I also have to "prove" that $\frac 1{n!}$ is a null series, since I merely proved that $\frac 1{n}$ is a null series.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic In that case, simply note that because $n! \geq n$, we have $\frac{1}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: true, thanks a million! You saved my day!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  how many of the factors in the denominator are greater than or equal to $n$?  Replace the denominator with something smaller that is still large enough to make the fraction go to zero.

Comment: What justifies the replacement of the denominator?

Comment: If you decrease the denominator, you increase the fraction.  Then we use the comparison test.

Comment: I can't use that. I have a really limited amount of tools I can work with. 1. $z_n$ is  null sequence if $|z|<1$, 2. $z_n$ is divergent if $|z|>1$. Furthermore I know about the squeeze theorem.

Comment: The comparison test is essentially the same as the squeeze theorem.  We are squeezing your fraction between a larger one that is easy to compute and zero.  Then we show the larger one goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$,$x_n=\frac{n^n}{(2n)!}$.
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\cdot \frac{n+1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=0$,so by the ratio test $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}x_n=0$.

Comment: Thanks, but  I can't that method.

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic just google "ratio test for sequences", you should easily find what this test implies.

Comment: I am very certain that this has not been lectured.